# For loop to generate plots when filtering on two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following pandas dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data =\
{'sheet': ['AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'AB0', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP', 'QG1IP'],
 'rep': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'sample': ['AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AS9', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO', 'AIO'],
 'variable': ['weight loss', 'weight loss', 'weight loss', 'weight loss', 'weight loss', 'weight loss', 'weight loss', 'weight loss', 'weight loss', 'weight loss', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'counts', 'mandy', 'mandy', 'mandy', 'mandy', 'mandy', 'mandy', 'mandy', 'mandy', 'mandy', 'mandy', 'mass', 'mass', 'mass', 'mass', 'mass', 'mass', 'mass', 'mass', 'mass', 'mass', 'andy', 'andy', 'andy', 'andy', 'andy', 'andy', 'andy', 'andy', 'andy', 'andy', 'irene', 'irene', 'irene', 'irene', 'irene', 'irene', 'irene', 'irene', 'irene', 'irene', 'lee', 'lee', 'lee', 'lee', 'lee', 'lee', 'lee', 'lee', 'lee', 'lee'],
 'value': [11.0, 11.0, 10.0, 1.0, 11.0, 13.0, 0.6, 120.0, 110.0, 113.0, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 3.4804, 5.6209999999999996, 5.851999999999999, 3.4804, 3.4804, 3.4804, 3.4804, 3.4804, 3.4804, 5.390000000000001, 2084.33734939759, 16.86746987951807, 1963.855421686747, 1771.0843373493974, 1819.2771084337348, 12.048192771084336, 12.048192771084336, 14.457831325301203, 4.819277108433735, 8.433734939759034, 195.0, 85.0, 102.5, 180.0, 60.75000000000001, 64.25, 90.83333333333334, 67.00000000000001, 93.33333333333334, 73.08333333333334, 237.89473684210526, 85.57894736842105, 44.10526315789474, 32.21052631578948, 21.68421052631579, 452.63157894736844, 56.52631578947369, 12.000000000000002, 101.36842105263158, 43.473684210526315, 2.3324399999999996, 1.07415, 2.3324399999999996, 1.07415, 1.07415, 2.3324399999999996, 1.07415, 1.07415, 2.3324399999999996, 1.07415]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I can plot the individual datapoints on a sns swarmplot buy filtering on two columns of interest, 'sheet' and 'variable', then plot that data using the following code.

```
plt.figure()
p = sns.swarmplot(data=df.loc[(df['sheet'] == 'AB0') & (df['variable'] == 'mandy')], 
                  hue='sample', 
                  x='sample', 
                  y='value').set(title= ('HG25 mandy'))
```

[image: sns swarmplot, manual filtering]

If I want to plot the whole dataframe, I'd have to do a lot of manually changing the filters, and renaming each plot. To overcome this, I have tried to put the 'sheet' unique values and the 'variable' unique values into their own lists, then use a for loop (maybe a nested for loop) to iterate over the dataframe, to plot the data for each sheet unique value and for each variable, but it doesnt seem to quite work. It appears that multiple plots are being plotted for the two unique values in 'sheet', but the filtering on values is missed:

```
sheet_list = df['sheet'].unique().tolist()
variable_list = df['variable'].unique().tolist()

for sheet in sheet_list:
    for variable in variable_list:
        plt.figure(variable)
        p = sns.swarmplot(data=df.loc[df['sheet'] == sheet], 
                          hue='sample', 
                          x='sample', 
                          y='value').set(title= (sheet + ' ' + variable))
        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
        plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I achieve this? Please note that the variables for each sheet unique entry are different (e.g. QG1IP has mass as a variable, whereas AB0 does not).

Comment: Strictly speaking, it’s a violation of visualization theory to doubly encode a variable; you should not do both `x=` and `hue=` the same variable.

Comment: `g = sns.catplot(data=df, kind='swarm', x='sample', y='value', col='sheet', row='variable', height=3.5)`

Comment: `g = sns.catplot(data=df, kind='swarm', x='sample', y='value', col='sheet', hue='variable', height=3.5, sharey=False, size=3)`

Comment: `g = sns.catplot(data=df, kind='swarm', x='sample', y='value', hue='sheet', col='variable', col_wrap=3, height=3.5, sharey=False, size=3)`

Comment: You should be using `catplot` with `kind='swarm`', not iterating through `df`. You can choose whatever options you want for `col`, `row`, and `hue`, but don't use the same column for multiple parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> the filtering on values is missed

Here's where you do the filtering:

> `p = sns.swarmplot(data=df.loc[df['sheet'] == sheet] ...`

In the original code you filtered on both 'sheet' and 'variable', but now you only filter on 'sheet'.

Just put the part back in to filter on 'variable' (the `& (df['variable'] == 'mandy')` in the original code) and you will be filtering on both again.

Comment: I want to each 'variable' too. So I amended the code with & (df['variable'] == variable (to iterate through the list of variables created). It seems to plot the AB0 data fine, but when it comes to the QG1IP data I get this error "ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence". Not sure if this is because the values in 'variable' are different between AB0 and QG1IP

Comment: So put the value of `variable` that you want on each iteration in place of the literal `'mandy'`.